# PHP - Implode multi-dimensional array for MySQL

Tags: php

I'm attempting to implode a multi-dimensional array with the characters `)`,`(`, so that
i can use a query similar to this:

> insert into table temp (a,b,c) 
>   values ('a','b','c'),('d','e','f');

Here is an example of the multidimentional array:

```
    $tmp = array(
              array(0 => 'CompanyB',
                    1 => 'IndustryA',
                    2 => 'Sysadmin',
                    3 => '01',
                    4 => '2011',
                    5 => '12',
                    6 => '2012',
                    7 => 'aeere',
                    8 => 'R6000',
                    9 => 'asdfasdf'),
              array(0 => 'CompanyC',
                    1 => 'IndustryC',
                    2 => 'Aabb',
                    3 => '02',
                    4 => '2012',
                    5 => '01',
                    6 => '2013',
                    7 => 'asdf',
                    8 => 'R7000',
                    9 => 'adfasdfeeeeeeeeeeeeeee'),
              array(0 => 'CompanyD',
                    1 => 'IndustryARR',
                    2 => 'NJNNLK',
                    3 => '01',
                    4 => '2011',
                    5 => '01',
                    6 => '2012',
                    7 => 'Anotheron',
                    8 => 'R9000',
                    9 => 'qweqweqwe'));
```

this does not produce any result, `print implode("),(",$tmp);`

I'm not a professional php developer, maybe there's an easier way to do this.
Appreciate your input.

Comment: implode only works on simple arrays. you'll have to implode in a loop.

Comment: Just use a prepared statement instead. It will be faster and easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$rows = array(); // will hold all table rows to insert
foreach ($tmp as $row) { // loops through your datasets
    $row_string = ''; // will hold the string for this row
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        // make sure that value is escaped
        $row_string .= '"' . addslashes($value) . '", ';
    }
    $row_string = '(' . substr($row_string, 0, -2) . ')'; // trim last ", " and wrap in brackets
    $rows[] = $row_string; // push row to rows array
}
$rows = implode(', ', $rows); // glue rows together into one string
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm guessing the first foreach loop cycles through the array keys.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dig on the 2nd level of your arrays.

One solution:

```
foreach($tmp as $v){
 echo "(".implode("),(",$v).")";
}
```

Comment: That gave me same result as:   for($i = 0;$i < count($tmp);$i++)
             {
              print array_values($tmp[$i]);
      }